# Footnote references in the footnote section losing their style affiliation when cut and pasted from within the same doc

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a problem where (at least some of the time, does not happen always) when I cut text from my thesis and paste it elsewhere in the same document, the "footnote reference" style of the number (in the footnote section) will paste as "default paragraph" style rather than the original footnote reference style.

The pasting preference (within document) is set to "merge formatting" - trying to swap it to "keep original" or "use destination style" will inexplicably apply "footnote style" to the main text (with the same issue applying to the footnote reference in the footnote section. This is driving me crazy and will invariably result in me missing some instance of this happening.

Any advice? I'd consider myself a fairly advanced word user and have tried fiddling with the default settings. Google hasn't turned up anything of use. In the attached example, I pasted a couple of sentences at the end of another sentence which had "normal" styling on it:
[image of the problem, with the recently pasted text and corresponding footnote in grey highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwoI0.png)

The template is custom, made by me, if that is useful info. Selecting the footnote reference number and applying the correct style works fine, but I need this to not happen at all.

Edit: Cross-posted at [MS Office Forums](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/46104-footnote-references-footnote-section-losing-their-style.html) due to relevant obscurity of issue. If the issue is resolved on either forum I will update the other to notify other users encountering the same issue.

Many thanks in advance!
Embla

**Update: partly-solved**, by looking more closely at copy/paste settings as suggested by macropod: https://www.msofficeforums.com/156154-post4.html

I did a repair of Word and also tried the trick for a corrupt document, neither had an effect. I then had another look at my advanced copy/paste setttings and set them all to default.

This seems to fix it - i.e. using "merge styles" (in the pasting-pop up) or "use destination styles" (in adv. settings) when pasting within the document will erase the footnote reference style from the footnote marker. This seems... not how it's meant to be, to put it mildly. Would be curious to know whether this is in fact normal word behaviour that others can replicate...?

But at least I think I can cut and paste now without needing to double check my footnotes every single time, so thanks macropod! :)

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/46104-footnote-references-footnote-section-losing-their-style.html  -- If you have cross-posted elsewhere forum etiquette would include posting a link to each forum's post in each forum post to avoid duplication of effort. In addition, when you get an answer in any of them, you should link in the others to that answer.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up. I will amend appropriately, and I had full intention of following either post up by marking it answered and linking to the other - it did not however occur to me to actually include a link to my cross-post. :)

Comment: See solution by macropod at cross-posted thread.